# Is an inline function a background task?

Tags: vb.net, function, task, background-process

I'm using this function (I call it inline function as I didn't know what the common name for that is):

```
Private Shared _fixationDataStream As FixationDataStream

Private Shared Sub CreateAndVisualizeSensitiveFilteredFixationsStream()
    _fixationDataStream = _host.Streams.CreateFixationDataStream()
    _fixationDataStream.Begin(Function(x, y, __)
                                  Debug.Print(vbLf & "Fixation started at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                                  _fixationBeginTime = DateTime.Now
                              End Function).Data(Function(x, y, __)
                                                     Debug.Print("During fixation, currently at: X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                                                 End Function).[End](Function(x, y, __)
                                                                         Debug.Print("Fixation ended at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)

                                                                         If _fixationBeginTime <> Nothing Then
                                                                             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
                                                                             Debug.Print("Fixation duration: {0}", DateTime.Now - _fixationBeginTime)
                                                                             Console.ForegroundColor = _defaultForegroundColor
                                                                         End If
                                                                     End Function)
End Sub
```

When I use a Background Task or a FolderWatcher and do something within it like raising event, it goes horribly wrong.

I would like to know if this can happen here, too.

How does this inline function operate?

Does it run in an endless loop? And if yes, where do it get its signal to stop?

And would it be possible to use an AddHandler instead of this inline function?

Thank you.

This is how the functions like Begin, Next and End are declared:

```
Namespace Tobii.Interaction
Public Class FixationDataStream
    Inherits DataStreamBase(Of FixationDataBehavior, FixationData)

    Public Sub New(fixationDataBehavior As FixationDataBehavior, hasSubscribersChanged As Action, enabled As Boolean)

    Public Function Begin(action As Action(Of Double, Double, Double)) As FixationDataStream
    Public Function [End](action As Action(Of Double, Double, Double)) As FixationDataStream
    Public Function Data(action As Action(Of Double, Double, Double)) As FixationDataStream
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: An inline function is passed as a lambda argument.  The thing that is called does whatever it wants to do with it, which should be documented as part of the API.  It might invoke it once.  It might invoke it repeatedly.  It might not invoke it at all at this point and remember it to be invoked later.  When the delegate is invoked, it operates like a function call from the location where it is called.

Comment: Also, an `Action` should be a `Sub` not a `Function`.

Comment: You can't use `AddHandler`, which is for setting an event handler, but I believe you could use `AddressOf` if you have an existing `Sub` which matches the signature of the `Action`.

Comment: Whether something can go horribly wrong on raising an event in your `Sub` depends entirely on what the API does with your `Sub`.

Comment: @Craig Could you post an example code on how use AddressOf in that trifold monster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AddressOf` instead of inline lambdas if you have a routine with the right signature.  Consider something like the following:

```
Sub BeginRoutine(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal z As Double)
    '...
End Sub

Sub DataRoutine(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal z As Double)
    '...
End Sub

Sub EndRoutine(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal z As Double)
    '...
End Sub
```

Then, you can use `AddressOf` to make delegates to pass to the API, e.g.

```
_fixationDataStream.Begin(AddressOf BeginRoutine).Data(AddressOf DataRoutine).[End](AddressOf EndRoutine)
```

Whether it's better to use inline lambdas or `AddressOf` depends on your code base.  If all you need are one-offs, then inline is usually more convenient.  On the other hand, if you will need to use the same routine for the purpose in more than one place, then `AddressOf` will probably be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. That cleared the question totally because you showed how it works.

Comment: I'm still having a problem in your line .Begin(AdressOf ...). The compiler says "An instance member of a class can't be reference without an explicit instance of a class by a shared method / member."

Comment: I made it "Private Shared Sub BeginRoutine" now, and it compiles.

Comment: To add to this, using the lambda hides the method from the rest of your code, and allows the code therein to access variables in the scope of the calling method. For example `_fixationBeginTime` may be declared in that method, and modified by the lambda. Whereas the Sub in `AddressOf <Sub>` has its own private scope and couldn't access a variable defined in the calling method. Another difference is that edit-and-continue of a lambda during debug will sometime not work, and you may be forced to restart your debugger, while a Sub is more forgiving.

Comment: @tmighty I'll edit the answer to add details about when `Shared` is needed.  I did a quick test, but I used a `Module` (which is automatically `Shared`) to do it.  Might not have time to do it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This is using method chaining (called fluent syntax) in which each method called returns the object. It's hard to know for sure what your code does just from this one method call, but it looks like it's starting with an object called `_fixationDataStream`. The object is unknown, since you didn't post the declaration in your code. The object has a method called `Begin` which takes an `Action` method, which you are passing in an anonymous function. It's returning the object back to you and you are calling a `Data` method on that. Again, you are passing in an anonymous method and it's returning that object back to you. Finally, you are calling another method called `End`, in which you are passing in an anonymous function.

That's what you're doing, but to describe what it's actually doing is impossible without more source code.

To answer your other questions, it's not running in an endless loop (well it could be, but most likely it's not) and no, you cannot use `AddHandler` because there aren't events.